# Instantly switch between dark and light mode for Windows

Tags: windows, themes, darkmode, lightmode

How to programmatically switch between dark and light mode for Windows.
I used registry keys,

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize\AppsUseLightTheme
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize\SystemUsesLightTheme
```

But it does not execute the command directly like a toggle switch in the Color Settings\Personalize\Colors window.

Windows does not respond immediately to dark or light mode changes via registry keys

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell scripts to achieve that. Example:

**Enable Darkmode on Apps**

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name AppsUseLightTheme -Value 0 -Type Dword -Force
```

**Enable Lightmode on Apps**

```
Remove-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name AppsUseLightTheme
```

Comment: I did this previously using PowerShell, but the taskbar and windows are not responding, such as changes in the settings window

Comment: @Mahmoud When i use the Light- & Darkmode toggles in the settings app it wont change the appearance of the taskbar either. Maybe a reboot still is required?

Comment: It is possible that there is an undocumented function that instantly applies the theme mode without the need to log off or restart Windows.

Comment: My method (see answer) changes it immediately (when th event run, but set it for 30 seconds later in the task manager and you'll see: no need to reboot, that's the idea)

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an event in Windows tasks scheduler for every mode you want (light and dark, for example).
There, in actions tab, set "start a program" with Powershell in program or script (type the following line):

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

And in "add optional args", insert this line (change `AppsUseLightTheme` for the var you wanna set and the value 0/1 depending on the time of day):

`Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name AppsUseLightTheme -Value 1`

Also, to answer some of the comments in @Bender110001 answer, you got 2 vars for custom theme in Win11 (maybe 10 too):

- `AppsUseLightTheme` for applications (Pycharm, browser pages, etc)
- `SystemUseLightTheme` for system colors (as you can see in the Win customization manual config: taskbar, windows, OS style out of apps).